# Do i need to handle or ignore the IOException fired by OutputStream close() function?

Tags: java, io, outputstream

In the following code the close function for outPutStream throw an IOException exception that I should catch. My question is do I need to handle it? Since I'm working with mobile devices and I want to make sure that I free all resources that I use, or could I safely ignore the exception.

```
//...
OutputStream output = null;
try {
     output = connection.getOutputStream();
     output.write(query.getBytes(charset));
} finally {
     if (output != null) try { 
        output.close(); 
     } catch (IOException e) {
        // Do i need to do something here ?
     }
}
```

Comment: You should never ignore exceptions that could be thrown, have a look at the Try-With resources block new in Java 7, it will may this code look a little prettier: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Comment: What can you do with it?

Comment: Yeah, that one has always made me scratch my head.  What I always do is just log the error, so that if it ever happens I know it did—but I have no clue what one would have to do to recover in this situation (if anything).

Comment: Hunter McMillen: but the try-with-resources block you're recommending can have the effect of ignoring the exception that Jimmy's asking how to handle. Read your link's discussion of "suppressed" exceptions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the close doesn't work, what can you do?

The only thing you can do is just log the exception, and as @mprabhat has suggested you can set the reference to null to speed up GC.

Comment: Does it make sense to call flush() ? or it cant be performed.

Comment: I think that would throw IOException as well

Comment: I think it dosent make sense, after a little reading close will call flush first.

Comment: In my comment above, I am assuming that we are in the condition that your close() has already thrown an exception.

Comment: Sorry, im not referring to your comment. i was talking about my first assumption. Thanks for follow up.

Answer (score 3):

The java documentation doesn't detail on which all different condition close will throw an `IOException` hence there isn't much that one can do.

At least you can set the reference of `OutputStream` to null and log the exception.

Answer (score 0):

In worst case, you can give a warning. But generally, such exceptions are thrown when trying to close an already closed session. In this case, you don't need to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

In Effective Java Joshua Bloch mentions this as one of the exceptions you might want to ignore. Generally though, he says, you do want to do more with exceptions than just logging them.